# Resource Not Found Exception API 24 android

Tags: java, android

I created my application, it worked fine but suddenly it stopped working. I got a Resource not found exception.Unfortunately it stopped working on all the devices at the same time.
Here is the Github link to my application :

> https://github.com/ronaksakhuja/A2_2k16/tree/master/app/src/main/java/notes/ronak/com/a22k16

Here is my logcat :

```
09-18 09:09:44.615 2684-2684/notes.ronak.com.a22k16 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                  Process: notes.ronak.com.a22k16, PID: 2684
                                                                  android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
                                                                      at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1351)
                                                                      at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:804)
                                                                      at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:771)
                                                                      at notes.ronak.com.a22k16.Timetable$MyListAdapter.getView(Timetable.java:140)
                                                                      at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2346)
                                                                      at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1280)
                                                                      at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1188)
                                                                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                                                                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
                                                                      at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1630)
                                                                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
                                                                      at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:715)
                                                                      at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
                                                                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                                                                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                                      at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
                                                                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                                                                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
                                                                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
                                                                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
                                                                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                                                                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                                                                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
                                                                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
                                                                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
                                                                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                                                                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2643)
                                                                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
                                                                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2100)
                                                                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1216)
                                                                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1452)
                                                                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1107)
                                                                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6013)
                                                                      at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
                                                                      at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
                                                                      at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
                                                                      at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

My Resources.java , View.java present in the SDK folder in the computer suddenly turns out to have a lot of errors.I didn't even touch them.
Tried clean and rebuild. Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when you put drawables in specific folder like drawable-v21 etc. Please check where you have put your images in which folder?